# Copy of large table in MYSQL weights 3 times more than the original table

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

After creating a copy from [Table1] (original table), I noticed that the new table [Table2] is much bigger that the original. Please see screenshots and structures below:

```
CREATE TABLE 'Table1'
 'A' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 'B' int(6) NOT NULL,
 'C' varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
 'D' text,
 'E' varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
 'F'set('UNKNOWN','ZZZ','YYY','XXX','WWW','VVV','UUU','TTT','SSS','RRR') NOT NULL,
 'G' date NOT NULL,
 'H' date DEFAULT NULL,
 'sent_F' date DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY ('A'),
 UNIQUE KEY 'unique_C' ('C','G'),
 KEY 'B' ('B'),
 KEY 'F' ('F'),
 KEY 'G' ('G'),
 KEY 'sent_F' ('sent_F'),
 KEY 'H' ('H'),
 KEY 'C' ('C')
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31251953 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

[image: Table1]

```
CREATE TABLE 'Table2'
 'A' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 'B' int(6) NOT NULL,
 'C' varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
 'D' text,
 'E' varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
 'F'set('UNKNOWN','ZZZ','YYY','XXX','WWW','VVV','UUU','TTT','SSS','RRR') NOT NULL,
 'G' date NOT NULL,
 'H' date DEFAULT NULL,
 'sent_F' date DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY ('A'),
 UNIQUE KEY 'unique_C' ('C','G'),
 KEY 'B' ('B'),
 KEY 'F' ('F'),
 KEY 'G' ('G'),
 KEY 'sent_F' ('sent_F'),
 KEY 'H' ('H'),
 KEY 'C' ('C')
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31171617 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

[image: Table2]

***The way I've performed the duplicate [Table1]:***

```
Create [Table2] like [Table1];
Alter table [Table2] disable keys;
Insert into [Table2] select * from [Table1];
Alter table [Table2] enable keys;
```

Both tables contain same data and same rules were configured in both cases.

Can anyone please explain why is the copied table much bigger than the original one? Does it make scene? 2GB to 6GB?

Comment: Probably temporary data used during the re-building of the index, or something like that. Try to run an `OPTIMIZE TABLE` at the end, and see what you get after that.

Comment: Have you tried to dump the table and restore it? Can you describe the columns for us?

Comment: Thank you, guys!
I'll try everything you suggested and get back to you with results :)

Comment: Is the `SHOW CREATE TABLE [Table2]` the same as `[Table1]` (despite the creation process)?

Comment: Why are you disabling keys before insertion? Perhaps in the original table the key values are _pointed to_, as opposed to being duplicated for every row, hence occupying less space.

Comment: @misorude - I run OPTIMIZE TABLE and this is the new space usage of [TABLE2]: Data - 2.1GiB, index - 3.9GiB, Total - 5.9GiB. As you can see, almost nothing was changed.

Comment: @nicolasl - I tried to dump and restore [TABLE1] and experienced same issue. I've edited my question with columns description.

Comment: @danblack - I've edited my question with columns description.

Comment: Only difference seems to be this `ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT` thingie. By any chance, do you see any difference after `ALTER TABLE Table2 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC`?

Comment: Do you really need the "D" field as TEXT? Text fields are huge.

Comment: Can you to change the ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT to ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED in both tables and redo the copy?

Comment: @StockOverflaw - I see "Compact" in the images for both.

Comment: Please provide `SELECT COUNT(*), AVG(LENGTH(c)), AVG(LENGTH(d)) FROM table1;` and table2.

Comment: What was the setting of `innodb_file_per_table`?

Comment: Did you notice the warning that says that InnoDB does not support `ALTER .. DISABLE KEY ..`